# Check if string ends with any of multiple characters

Tags: javascript

How would I check to see if a string ends in any one of multiple characters? Currently this code returns false, even though the string ends in a question mark.The properly working code would return true if the string ends in either a period, exclamation mark, or question mark, and return false if its last character is anything else.

Obviously I could check these conditions independently but suppose I had a very long list, surely there is a better way?

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str = "Hello?";
    var n = str.endsWith(".", "!", "?");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`endsWith` just doesn’t take multiple strings to test. You could define an array of them and check each value with `endsWith`:

```
function endsWithAny(suffixes, string) {
    return suffixes.some(function (suffix) {
        return string.endsWith(suffix);
    });
}

function myFunction() {
    var str = "Hello?";
    var n = endsWithAny([".", "!", "?"], str);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

Or use a regular expression for a one-off:

```
var n = /[.!?]$/.test(str);
```

Comment: Would the RegEx not be `^.*[.!?]$`? I'm not familiar with Javascript's implementation of RegEx so I could be wrong

Comment: @e_i_pi: That would be equivalent, sure. The one here isn’t anchored to the start of the string, though. `test` will match anywhere (unlike Python’s `match`, for example, if that type of API is what you’re thinking of).

Comment: Using typescript:

`function endsWithAny(suffixes: string[], search: string): boolean {
    return suffixes.some( (suffix: string): boolean => search.endsWith(suffix) );
}`

Answer (score 7):

for some reason the accepted answer's function was giving me problems so I wrote this function that works for me:

```
//check if string ends with any of array suffixes
function endsWithAny(suffixes, string) {
    for (let suffix of suffixes) {
        if(string.endsWith(suffix))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

so then your function is

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = "Hello?";
    var n = endsWithAny([".", "!", "?"], str);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `indexOf` in combination with `slice`:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str = "Hello?";
    var n = '.!?'.indexOf(str.slice(-1)) >= 0;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: This only works for one single character suffix.