# Joining array elements inside map based on rule not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to fix an issue with a string that's split into an array, the issue being that titles such as Mr. etc are split points when I don't want them to be.

I had an idea to reprocess the array using map() and try and join back up any truncated elements (specifically those that end in "Mr." , "Mrs." etc. My code doesn't work and I'm not sure if it's actually possible to look ahead inside the map() and join two array indexes together, or if I'm fundamentally approaching the problem from the wrong angle.

Here's my code:

```html
var origstr = "During July of this year I completed a two week work placement with Bruce and Carry Ltd, a national insurance company with an annual turnover of £24 million. I worked as an Accounting Assistant with Mr. Bench, where I was given responsibility for financial reporting and for assisting the senior credit controller by sending invoices to debtors.";

// TEXT INPUT SPLIT AND PROCESS
// Step 1: split full text input into sentence chunks
var arr1 = origstr.match(/([^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+)|([^\.!\?]+$)/g); // split

// Step 2: check for terms like Mr. or Ltd. if so, merge back into the correct sentence
// Step 3: remove leading whitespace from array elements, return array
var arr2 = arr1.map(function (el, index) {
  if (endsWithAny(["Mr.", "Mrs.", "Ltd.", "Dept.", "I.T."], el)){
      el = [el[index],el[index+1]].join();
  }
  return el.trim();
});

// extends endswith() to work with arrays
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45069514/check-if-string-ends-with-any-of-multiple-characters
function endsWithAny(suffixes, string) {
    return suffixes.some(function (suffix) {
        return string.endsWith(suffix);
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the desired output at the end?

Comment: Return a new array as str2, now a different length, as some elements have been merged. e.g. a sentence that originally ended with Mr. would be merged with the next one that starts with "Bench".

Comment: only when certain string matches are made at the end of the sentence, most likely Mr. or Mrs. I was using endsWith() to check if true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To split into sentences you can iterate over the splitted elements and decide if a sentence has ended or not with an element or your splitted array like the snippet below. This does not cover sentences ending with "?" or "!", you will have to apply this as well.

```js
var text = "During July of this year I completed a two week work placement with Bruce and Carry Ltd., a national insurance company with an annual turnover of £24 million. \
I worked as an Accounting Assistant with Mr. Bench, where I was given responsIbIlIty for fInancIal reportIng and for assIstIng the senIor credIt controller by sendIng InvoIces to debtors.";

function endsWithAny(suffixes, string) {
  return suffixes.some(function(suffix) {
    return string.endsWith(suffix);
  });
}

function splitSentences(input) {
  var splitted = input.split(".");
  var sentences = [];
  var cur = "";

  splitted.forEach((part, idx) => {
    if (idx === splitted.length - 1 || !endsWithAny(["Mr", "Mr", "Ltd", "Dept", "I.T"], part)) {
      cur += part;
      if (cur) {
        sentences.push(cur.trim())
      };
      cur = "";
    } else {
      cur += part+".";
    }
  });
  return sentences;
}


console.info(splitSentences(text));
```

Comment: That worked well thanks. Two questions: when I tried my regular expression in place of the split(), it didn't work- the array remained the same. Any idea why? Also, is it personal preference why you went for a forEach instead of map() or is it more suitable for this purpose? Thanks again.